# EF Core Composite Key, one foreign, one auto incrementing

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this entity:

```
public class PlayerScoreHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PlayerScoreId { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScoreWhen { get; set; }
}
```

I need to make a composite key out of both of those `Id` fields. `PlayerScoreId` needs to be a foreign key to `PlayerScore.Id` . `Id` needs to be an auto incrementing id.

So, I got as far as:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<PlayerScoreHistory>()
        .HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.PlayerScoreId });
}
```

This gives me the composite key. I did `Add-Migration Initial` to give me my initial migration.

To get the Foreign Key, I simply added the line in the `constraints` parameter:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "PlayerScoreHistories",
    columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            PlayerScoreId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            ScoreWhen = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
        },
    constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_PlayerScoreHistories", x => new { x.Id, x.PlayerScoreId });
            table.ForeignKey("FK_PlayerScoreId", arg => new {  arg.PlayerScoreId}, "PlayerScores", "Id");
        });
```

So two questions:

1. How can I get the foreign key creation in the `OnModelCreating` method?
2. How can I make the `Id` column a Database Generated field and make sure EF Core doesn't try and set a value?

I'm not exactly sure what options are open to me, seeing as EF Core is extremely new...

The two errors I get:

### 1.

When I add this line to the `Id` `column` parameter configuration:

```
Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
```

I get

> SQL Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF [duplicate]

### 2.

When I remove the line and then try and add an entity, I get:

> Can't insert null into column `Id`

---

Clearly I'm in between somewhere....

---

### Edit So Far

I decided to remove the `Id` column and just use `PlayerScoreId` and `ScoreWhen` as the composite keys....

But, one question I still have is how to make `OnModelCreating` identity `PlayerScoreId` as a foreign key - without having navigation properties.....

Comment: I see you added update now. Your question is not really clear. Can you explain a little more about the question you have?

Comment: My first two questions still stand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, one question I still have is how to make OnModelCreating identity PlayerScoreId as a foreign key - without having navigation properties.....

You can use the `HasOne` / `WithMany` (or `HasMany` / `WithOne`) methods w/o specifying the navigation property, combined with `HasForeignKey` as usual:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerScoreHistory>()
    .HasOne<PlayerScore>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.PlayerScoreId);
```

Comment: Oh really, well there you go! I thought it was based on the properties of the the entity (I was a bit tired when i was looking at it).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, editing migration files give you desired database as you want but EF runtime will not be aware about those changes. All the information which runtime requires should be configured in the model only.

Therefore you get exception

> SQL Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF [duplicate]

Because EF runtime does not know about identity column so it will send 0 (`default(int)`) as the value for identity column in the insert statement.

I am not able to get second exception since, EF will not (& cannot) try to insert null for `int` type property because value could not be null in c# world.

Now answers to your questions:

1. Answer of Ivan is correct. That is the way to configure foreign key in modelbuilder.

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerScoreHistory>()
       .HasOne<PlayerScore>()
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.PlayerScoreId);
   ```

For more info on how to configure relationships - https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html

2. To tell that `Id` is database generated field, use following code in modelbuilder.

   ```
   modelBuilder
       .Entity<PlayerScoreHistory>()
       .Property(e => e.Id)
       .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
   ```

This will tell EF that values for `Id` are generated while inserting entity, which for SqlServer translate to `Identity` if there is only 1 integer column configured for `ValueGeneratedOnAdd`. More info on generated properties is at https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/generated-properties.html#value-generated-on-add

Comment: Yeah that `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` is what I was looking for. thanks